# Measure bandwidth used by a single program execution

Tags: monitoring, bandwidth

I'd like to measure the bandwidth consumed by a single program launch (for processes launched from cron, in order to get an idea of how much BW they are using). I know of nethogs and the many other commands that measure bandwidth per device/port.

Ideally, it would be something like trickle, which is prepended to the command and on finalization reports the data used. My research comes up with no results.

My only alternative idea is to use ifconfig to get the bytes transmitted before launch and after finalization, but this is obviously very rough. Ideas for anything better?

I guess trickle could be used as the easier starting point for such a program, if one had enough time for coding it...

Answer (score 0):

`nethogs` does this: http://nethogs.sourceforge.net/, install it using the software center.

I believe that `sysdig` could be used, too but I don't have the syntax at hand.

Comment: What's `sysdig`? There's a manpage only for 14.10, and that turns up empty: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/en/man8/sysdig.8.html

Comment: Sorry, forgot the link: https://github.com/draios/sysdig/

Comment: AFAIK nethogs is "interactive" and shows only instantaneous info.

Answer (score 0):

One way I can think for transmitted data is to use iptables, while running the program under some unique matchable condition, such as a separate group.

First, pick a group which you belong to and under which no processes are running:

```
$ for i in $(groups); do echo $i $(pgrep -c -G $i); done | awk '$2 == 0'
cdrom 0
sudo 0
plugdev 0
lpadmin 0
sambashare 0
debian-tor 0
libvirtd 0
```

I'll pick `debian-tor`. Now add an iptables rule which will match traffic originating from process in this group. This will need root access, so add `sudo` to all the `iptables` commands:

```
iptables -N STATS  # Create a new chain
iptables -A STATS -p tcp -j RETURN # And let it do nothing
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m owner --gid-owner debian-tor -j STATS
```

Start your application:

```
sg debian-tor 'ssh a.friendly.system "cat - >/dev/null" </dev/zero'
```

Check the stats:

```
$ iptables -vL  STATS
Chain STATS (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
 148K  393M ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere
```

This won't work for received data. :(

---

The other way could be to use `/proc/$PID/netstat`, if you can convince your application to stay alive long enough:

```
$ awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {($i~/(In|Out)Octets/) && a[i] = 1}; z=""; for (i=1; i<=NF; i++){(a[i] == 1) && z = z " " $i}; if (z) {print z}}' /proc/12307/net/netstat 
 InOctets OutOctets
 254543569761 2144044764834
```

(All that `awk` code is to look for the `InOctects` and `OutOctects` columns in the `netstat` file.)

Unfortunately, `/proc/$PID/net` is simply `/proc/net`, so that the information is common to all processes. Reading `netstat` doesn't give any information about the particular process.

Comment: If you launch the process in suspended state and open its netstat file, will the later remain readable after it finishes? Mmm...

Comment: @Alex the file vanishes when the process ends. At any rate, it seems I was mistake about the netstat file. It's the same for all processes, and is actually `/proc/net/netstat`.